# Conversion from *UMat to Iplimage

Tags: opencv, iplimage

I have an old OpenCV code using Iplimages which I want to use again for another application. Unfortunately the new application hands over an *UMat image. 
How can I convert this *UMat image to an Iplimage?

This is a short version of my Code

```
void doImageProcessing(UMat* myFrame)
{
    IplImage *src_img;
    src_img = new IplImage(*myFrame); //conversion from *Umat to Iplimage
    [...]
 }
```